# Pandas: Detect missing columns between one df and another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd

expected_df = pd.DataFrame({'One': [20], 'Two': [30], 'Three': [90]})

df = pd.DataFrame({'One': [20], 'Two': [30]})

assert expected_df.equals(df), 'Test Failed: df is missing column/s'

# returns 'Test Failed: df is missing column/s'
```

As you can see 'df' does not contain the column 'Three', so running assert `equals()` returns 'Test Failed: df is missing column/s'.

What I would like is to be able to detect which column in missing and return it as part of the failed assertion, so something like 'Test Failed: df is missing column/s: ['Three']'

Is there a way to do that with assert and pandas?

Comment: You can use expected_df.eq(df), it gives you a True False df and assert from there

Answer (score 4):

Compute the difference between two lists:

```
>>> expected_df.columns.difference(df.columns).tolist()
['Three']
```